# Create multiple variable columns from single column value

Tags: sql-server

The following code gets the number of days for a specific month set in @month

```
DECLARE @month tinyint
, @Days varchar(max)

SET @month = 1 -January

;WITH DaysInMonth 
AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS float)) AS datetime)))) D
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, D)
    FROM DaysInMonth
    WHERE D < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS float)) AS datetime))))))
)
SELECT
   @Days = substring((SELECT ( ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(2), D, 104))
                           FROM DaysInMonth
                           FOR XML PATH( '' )
                          ), 3, 1000 )  FROM DaysInMonth

SELECT @Days
```

I am getting the following output in a single column:

01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31

How can I get these values in different columns?.

The main aim for get this query is to join or union with another query that contains records marked with 1 or 0 set to a specific date. The final query will output a result similar to the one a have below but, for the full month sent in the parameter.

```
July    28       29      30         31          01      02          03
NULL    Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday
Jhon    1        0      1           0           1       0           0
```

Any other solution to get around similar output is welcome.Thank you

Comment: So you just want 31 columns if the month has 31 days? What data will be in these columns? What will the columns be called? Won't you also need the year (think February)?

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand, yes, I would like the number of columns based on the number of days in a specific month. I'm not worried about the year yet as the results would be only for the current year. I am planing to join this query with data that falls under the specific date for roster shifts. The main aim of this query is to display some data in a calendar view format.

Comment: Can you explain your entire requirements in the question please? It's one thing to come up with dynamic column names, something completely different to put data in those columns to perform meaningful joins. If you show some actual roster data and how you want that to be output, we can probably make better recommendations (which may include formatting the data like a calendar on the client).

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand, I've updated my question, please see my desired oputput. Thank you.

Comment: The new sample output is confusing. Those are only seven days - is that July 28-31 and August 1-3? If so, then we are no longer talking about just the days in a single month... Can you show the full output you want to see for a given month, and for more than one user? Can you show the table structure and a few rows of sample data from the other table?

Answer (score 2):

---

For the modifications to the question, here is a modified query:

```
declare @month datetime = '20140708';

set datefirst 1;  -- align to Monday as first day of week

-- test data as per OP:
create table #t (
     Date       Date not null primary key
    ,IsActive   int  not null
);
insert #t(Date,IsActive)
values ('20140728', 1)
      ,('20140729', 0)
      ,('20140730', 1)
      ,('20140731', 0)
      ,('20140801', 1)
      ,('20140802', 0)
      ,('20140803', 0);

with  -- standard CTE-tally with values from 0 to 10,000
E1(N) as ( select 1 from (values 
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
    )E1(N)
),
E2(N) as ( select 1 from E1 a cross join E1 b ),
E4(N) as ( select 1 from E2 a cross join E2 b ),
tally as (
    select 0 as N union all
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by N) as N
    from E4
)

,calendar as (
    select top (datepart(dd,  eomonth(@month)))
         cast(dateadd(dd,tally.N,@month) as date) as Date
        ,N
    from tally
    where N > 0
)

select
     WeekNo
    ,max(isnull(Mon,0)) as Mon
    ,max(isnull(Tue,0)) as Tue
    ,max(isnull(Wed,0)) as Wed
    ,max(isnull(Thu,0)) as Thu
    ,max(isnull(Fri,0)) as Fri
    ,max(isnull(Sat,0)) as Sat
    ,max(isnull(Sun,0)) as Sun
from (
    select
         calendar.Date
        ,cast(datename(dw,calendar.Date) as char(3)) as WeekDay
        ,datepart(ww,calendar.Date) as WeekNo
        ,data.IsActive
    from calendar
    left join #t data
       on data.Date     = calendar.Date
) t
pivot ( max(IsActive) for WeekDay in (Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun)) pvt
group by WeekNo
;
go
```

yielding this:

```
WeekNo      Mon         Tue         Wed         Thu         Fri         Sat         Sun
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
28          0           0           0           0           0           0           0
29          0           0           0           0           0           0           0
30          0           0           0           0           0           0           0
31          1           0           1           0           1           0           0
32          0           0           0           0           0           0           0
```

---

fro the original question:
Not quite sure what this achieves, but the following works nicely:

```
declare @month datetime = '20140710';

with  -- standard CTE-tally with values from 0 to 10,000
E1(N) as ( select 1 from (values 
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
    )E1(N)
),
E2(N) as ( select 1 from E1 a cross join E1 b ),
E4(N) as ( select 1 from E2 a cross join E2 b ),
tally as (
    select 0 as N union all
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by N) as N
    from E4
)

select  -- the query requested by OP, using the CTE tally above
    [01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],
    [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
    [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],
    [31]
from (
    select top (datepart(dd, eomonth(@month)))
        right('0' + cast(N as varchar(2)),2) as X,
        N
    from tally
    where N > 0
) t pivot (max(X) for N in (
    [01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06],[07],[08],[09],[10],
    [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
    [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],
    [31] )
) pvt
;
```

to yield this:

```
01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31

(1 row(s) affected)
```

or with `@month int = '20140210' -- February` we get:

```
01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
01   02   03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   NULL NULL NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

No RDBMS tagged, so used SQL Server syntax above.

Comment: [This is a little tidier I think](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37499), but I agree, I'm not sure exactly what this achieves on its own, given the requirements touched on in the comments.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I love Dynamic SQL  when I can't avoid it, but in this case I will choose to avoid it. Half the query above is building a standard tally table which will (sooner or later) pre-exist as a table in most DB's.

Comment: What I don't like is typing out 1-31 in both the SELECT and PIVOT sections, which you can't just magically get from a numbers table, and you'll always have 31 columns in the output even for months with < 31 days, which seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Fair enough - the real determinant will be the needs of the actual use-case.

Comment: Also you have top 10,000 but you really only need 31 (or 42 if the OP includes days from adjacent months). And in case you need further prodding, the stacked CTE approach is [not the best performer](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3) - a calendar table would be much better, but barring that, I think if I were to choose between stacked CTEs and other approaches with negligible performance differences, it would be my last choice simply due to syntax complexity - especially since you added a recursive CTE at the end, which I didn't test but I'm sure would have an impact on performance...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Recursive CTE? Where? I copied the tally definition from an article by Jeff Moden where he touted it as the fastest CTE tally he knew of, beating out an earlier one he had published.

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the recursive part, I saw the UNION ALL and my spidey sense tingled. Anyway, my point remains: the negligible performance differences between that cumbersome syntax and much easier ways to derive the same sets - even in the absence of a numbers table - make it very hard to justify IMHO. And I still don't know why typing 1-31 manually - twice - is preferred over dynamic SQL.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I have spent half the last quarter (it feels like) writing dynamic SQL queries of 1,000 to 2,000 lines in length (because I have to push them across a linked server). Don't mind me if I stick with regular SQL for a bit eh?

Comment: I don't know that I agree that a recommendation you're making to other people about how they should write their T-SQL should be based solely on what you're tired of, and not other, more important factors that aren't based on your individual experience. *shrug* I'm not worried about what you like or don't like, but I do want to make sure that users know there are better ways than hard-coding 62 column names.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: For a temporary solution that lasted all of about 5 minutes, I can type 62 column names faster than I can think through the dynamic SQL to create them (the last quarter not withstanding). Also my understanding is that dynamic SQL query plans are less likely to get cached.

Comment: *shrug* Like I said, I'm not worried about what you like or don't like. And the caching thing hasn't been true in SQL Server for many, many versions now...

Comment: Thank you @AaronBertrand. This solution meets my needs for what I want to achieve. Apologies for not being clear enough about my requirements. I would like to stick with the solution proposed by Aaron in SQL Fiddle as I don't have to type all the days in the pivot query.